# ASP.NET - How to make a list item that when clicked, changes code behind (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multiview form with 4 views like this

```
            <div class="form_head">
                <ul>
                    <li class="personalInfo" id="personalInfo" runat="server">Personal Info</li>
                    <li class="travelingInfo" id="travelingInfo" runat="server">Traveling Info</li>
                    <li class="pointsOfInterest" id="pointsOfInterest" runat="server">Points of Interest</li>
                    <li class="revision" id="revision" runat="server">Revision</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Which looks like: 
[image]

How can I make for e.g if I directly click Points of Interests, it goes there instead of clicking 'next' twice? (How can I make list item clickable and change C# code, because to change from one view to another, you just need to implement `MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0/1/2 or 3;`

Comment: How you currently navigating to that view by clicking on "Next"? Same logic you need to apply there too.. Inside <li> tag you also need to create <a> tag which will make it clickable.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Well, I have a protected void Button_next1(object sender, EventArgs e) method, but i dont know how to 'spot' a click on a html element (lets say I create <a>, how do I know when that list item is clicked (in c# code))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the text in your LIs to `LinkButton` and remove `runat="server"` from the LIs

```
   <div class="form_head">
   <ul>
     <li class="personalInfo" id="personalInfo">
          <asp:LinkButton ID="personalInfoLink" runat="server" OnClick="personalInfoLink_Click">Personal Info</asp:LinkButton>
     </li>
     <!-- Repeat for the other links -->
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Then wire it up to the corresponding event handler

```
protected void personalInfoLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0/1/2 or 3;
}
```

> **Asyncronous PostBack:** To prevent postback every time you click each
>   link, try use UpdatePanel

Comment: Good! This works, but I had to add the runat="server" anyway to the list item because of 40 error pops hahaha. Thanks!